# Need help after instrumenting the jar in EMMA

Tags: code-coverage

I am new to Code Coverage and EMMA tool. 
I am trying to:
1. Write a simple java program "testClass1.java". Compile it, and a got a "testClass1.class" file.
2. I package this as a jar. "myJar.jar"
3. Instrument this jar using this emma command and got a coverage.em file
C:\Users\emahaboo\Desktop>java -cp emma-2.0.5312.jar emma instr -m overwrite -cp myJar.jar
EMMA: processing instrumentation path ...
EMMA: instrumentation path processed in 156 ms
EMMA: [1 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
EMMA: metadata merged into [C:\Users\emahaboo\Desktop\coverage.em] {in 7 ms}he emma command.

1. Now I want to execute this "myJar.jar" file.

I am not sure, what should I do exactly here, because I get the below error:

C:\Users\emahaboo\Desktop>java -cp myJar.jar:emma-2.0.5312.jar myJar
Error: Could not find or load main class myJar

C:\Users\emahaboo\Desktop>java -cp myJar.jar:emma-2.0.5312.jar testClass1
Error: Could not find or load main class testClass1

Can someone help me to proceed. I want to successfully run this program and get the emma code coverage report.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, items on the classpath need to be separated with semicolons. I would put the whole parameter in quotes:

```
-cp "myJar.jar;emma-2.0.5312.jar"
```

Comment: I tried this:
C:\Users\emahaboo\Desktop>java -cp "myJar.jar;emma-2.0.5312.jar"
And I got some help options...

Comment: I got my "coverage.em" file generated successfully. After this don't know how to proceed. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a jar file, there must be a main class as the entrance. For the error "Error: Could not find or load main class...", it just means that it can't find the main class. I think the root cause for this is due to your second step: "I package this as a jar. "myJar.jar"". when you packaged it, you need to set the testClass1 as the main class for this jar file. Hope this helps.